# How do i implement logic in get, set in dependency property WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

i have five textbox controls in a user control, i want to add a dependency property in such a way

```
    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Textbox1.Text.Trim() + "." + Textbox2.Text.Trim() + "." + Textbox3.Text.Trim() + "." + Textbox4.Text.Trim() + "|" + Textbox5.Text.Trim();
        }
        set
        {

            Textbox1.Text = value.Split('|')[0];
            Textbox2.Text = value.Split('|')[1];
            Textbox3.Text = value.Split('|')[2];
            Textbox4.Text = value.Split('|')[3];
            Textbox5.Text = value.Split('|')[4];
        }

    }
```

But it is not working. how do i create a dependency property which can be binded directly to a single property. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: *it is not working* is *not* a useful description.

Comment: Binding is not working.

Comment: Wow! You really don't get it, do you? You have to help us to help you. At the moment, you're not helping us at all, so you won't get any/much help. It's up to you.

Comment: so please let me know how can i help you?

Comment: Read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Stack Overflow Help Center and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one solution:

- expose the full value with the property and use an `IValueConverter` to extract the parts
- create five properties, each exposing a part of the full value

Both are MVVM-compliant but the second one may be more transparent by avoiding too much plumbing but you may need more notification (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) calls.

---

EDIT: complete implementation

The `UserControl`:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SplitterControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:SplitConverter x:Key="splitConverter"></local:SplitConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="root" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=MyValue,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource splitConverter}}">
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="{Binding [0],NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox2" Text="{Binding [1],NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox3" Text="{Binding [2],NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox4" Text="{Binding [3],NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox5" Text="{Binding [4],NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class SplitterControl : UserControl
    {
        public string MyValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyValue", typeof(string), typeof(SplitterControl));        

        public SplitterControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
        {
            root.GetBindingExpression(DataContextProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

The `IValueConverter`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SplitConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value as string).Split('|');
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Join("|", value as string[]);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the parent control, e.g. the `MainWindow`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="input" Text="First|Second|Third|Fourth|Fifth"></TextBox>
    <local:SplitterControl MyValue="{Binding ElementName=input,Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay}"></local:SplitterControl>
```

Edit the `"input"` `TextBox` to change the full string value and edit each `TextBox` in the `UserControl` to change each part.

Very tricky but should do what you want.

Comment: Since it is a user control, i want to expose it as a single property. when i set the value it should get appear on different textboxes and when i get it should concatenate the values. (as above)